# отсутствие данных в post запросе AngularJS

Tags: ajax, angularjs, post

Есть контроллер:

```
betdeskApp.controller('regController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.email = '';
    $scope.password = '';
    $scope.action = 'registration';
    $scope.SendRequest = function()
    {
       $http.post(CreateHref($scope.action, $scope.email, $scope.password)).success(function (data) {
            $scope.regAnswer = data;
            console.log(data);
       });
    }
});

function CreateHref(action, email, password)
{
    var str = "../model/web/index.php" + "?" + "action=" + action + "&" + "email=" + email + "&" + "password=" + password;
   // console.log(str);
    return str;
}
```

При отправке данного запроса, в ответ приходит пустота.
Сервер на php и работает корректно.
Может я чего то не учел в контроллере при запросе?

Код отправки формы:

```
<form class="col-sm-6" action="../model/web/index.php" method="post">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="registration">
        <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="" ng-model="email">
    </div><br />
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" value="" ng-model="password">
    </div><br />
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i></span>
        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" ng-model="confPassword">
    </div><br />
    <div class="input-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Вот что получаю в логе:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если что-то не работает - первым делом надо смотреть ошибки в консоли

Comment: а так же проверить что именно происходит на сервере. Возможно именно пустоту он и возвращает

Comment: отредактировать свой вопрос и добавить в него недостающую информацию можно с помощью кнопки [edit] под вопросом

Comment: судя по ответу - сервер возвращает пустую строку. Стоит пройтись по шагам по функции сервера и увидеть ошибку

Comment: @Grundy при отправки запроса через `action` у меня происходит регистрация в БД а при отправке с помощью контроллера нет. По сути передаю то то же самое

Comment: Очевидно что ты передаешь не то же самое. у тебя даже количество переданных полей не совпадает, не говоря про то, что неизвестно откуда и как ты пытаешься получить параметры на сервере

Comment: @Grundy `confirmPass` - я не передаю - это заготовка для проверки правильности ввода пароля. На сервак я передаю `action email password` соответственно и логика там под эти три параметра сделана.

Comment: @Grundy когда я этиже параметры передаю с помощью `action` сервер отрабатывает..

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52515/discussion-between-grundy-and--).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тарас был в правильном направлении, его код:

```
 var config = {
    headers : {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
}

var data = "action=registration&email=test@gmail.com&password=123456&confirmPassword=123456";

$http.post('../model/web/index.php', data, config)
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data);
})
.error(function (data, status, header, config) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Затык получился в том, что переменную `data` необходимо правильно подготовить к передаче. Я это сделал так:

```
var data = $.param({ "action": $scope.action, "email": $scope.email, "password": $scope.password });
```

После этого все отлично заработало

Answer (score 1):

Должно работать:

```
var config = {
    headers : {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
}

var data = "action=registration&email=test@gmail.com&password=123456&confirmPassword=123456";

$http.post('../model/web/index.php', data, config)
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data);
})
.error(function (data, status, header, config) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52522/discussion-on-answer-by-taras-kovalenko----post--angular).